# Need to iterate all messages stored on an MS exchange server

Tags: exchange-server

I have a client who has asked me about developing a tool to sift through all of the mail on their corporate Exchange server to look for activity that would indicate a possible insider threat. I will have complete access to the server, if needed: ability to install plugins or other custom code, administrative passwords, etc.

The code needs to look through every message stored on the server now, and then be able to monitor incoming and outgoing message on a continuing basis.

I have been looking around for a few days, and have only discovered two possibilties: 1) turn on message tracking and import the logs, or 2) write an  EWS application that connects to Exchange to get the individual messages.

(1) is not ideal because I don't get the message body text, and (2) is sort of a pain because it requires me to poll the server continuously if I want the stream of new messages automatically.

I was hoping someone has some insight into the best way to meet the customer requirement...the Exchange docs have lots of bits-n-bytes examples but nothing that outlines the available approaches.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> > and then be able to monitor incoming and outgoing message on a continuing basis.

To do ongoing monitoring I would suggest you look at Transport Agents http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/01/21/how-to-write-an-exchange-2013-transport-agent.aspx these will allow you to process messages while they are in the Transport Pipeline (while being received and sent) and is how most Data leakage Protection providers etc. implement their solutions.

For scanning content that is already in the Exchange store then EWS is the best approach. If you have Exchange 2013 and there is particular content you search for them you might want to look at using eDiscovery.

Cheers
Glen